# Online store for Turkey with USD currency

Tags: paypal

I want to open and online store. I live in India, I will manage website and everything from India but my target customers are from Turkey. I want to integrate Paypal international payment for my website. But when my customers want to make payment in Turkish currency, PayPal is asking for PayPal account, not accepted for credit and debit card.

Turkish currency payment is not supported by credit and debit cards. That's why I'm thinking to fix the prices in US Dollars for selling the items from my website. Do you think that I can sell my items by US dollar in Turkey and credit and debit card option can work like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about something - just not programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to understand what country/jurisdiction "you" -- meaning whoever is in business here -- is in and then look up and abide by the policies (from the governments and from PayPal, which is subject to those governments). Then you can determine how currency will interact with that.

While the specific answers to these questions will change over time as regulation and products change, right now you are basically out of luck accepting PayPal payments with an Indian company due to PayPal's inability to operate in line with government regulations there. A Turkish company would not face the same issues (PayPal operates and offers more services in Turkey) but would be subject to other issues. And if you are not sure what country you are or should be operating in you need a business lawyer not a StackOverflow crowdsourced opinion :).

Changing the currency of the transaction to USD does not affect the nationality of the company (or individual) conducting the ecommerce. In some cases USD may avoid some regulations or issues, but in other cases it can introduce very serious issues (many countries,such as China, seriously restrict their citizens' ability to deal in nonlocal currency).